# Multi Modal adding header, body and buttons in JS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am using multi modal from here

https://github.com/ngzhian/multi-step-modal

Exactly speaking the third example (back buttons without progress bar).

https://www.ngzhian.com/multi-step-modal/

But what I have is prepared modal which I am fulfilling with data.
My modal:

```
<form class="modal multi-step" id="demo-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" id="modal-header">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary step step-1" data-step="1" onclick="sendEvent(2)" >Próximo</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and JS (it is piece of code from the loop)

```
    if (i == 0 || (i + 1) == files.length) {
        if (i == 0) {
            var header = '<h4 class="modal-title step-' + (i + 1) + '" data-step="' + (i + 1) + '"  > HEaderModal  </h4>';
            var body = '<div class="modal-body  step-' + (i + 1) + '" data-step="' + (i + 1) + '"  >This is step ' + (i + 1) + '.</div>';
            $("#modal-header").append(header);
            $("#modal-body").append(body);
        } else {
            var header = '<h4 class="modal-title step-' + (i + 1) + '" data-step="' + (i + 1) + '" > HEaderModal  </h4>';
            var body = '<div class="modal-body  step-' + (i + 1) + '" data-step="' + (i + 1) + '"  >This is step ' + (i + 1) + '.</div>';
            var footer = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary step step-' + (i + 1) + '" data-step="' + (i + 1) + '" onclick="sendEvent(' + (i) + ')" >Atrás</button>'
            $("#modal-header").append(header);
            $("#modal-body").append(body);                    
            $("#modal-footer").append(footer);
        }
    } else {
        var header = '<h4 class="modal-title step-' + (i + 1) + '" data-step="' + (i + 1) + '"> HEaderModal  </h4>';
        var body = '<div class="modal-body  step-' + (i + 1) + '" data-step="' + (i + 1) + '"  >This is step ' + (i + 1) + '.</div>';
        var footer = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary step step-' + (i + 1) + '" data-step="' + (i + 1) + '" onclick="sendEvent(' + (i) + ')" >Atrás</button> \
                      <button type="button" class ="btn btn-primary step step-' + (i + 1) + '" data-step="' + (i + 1) + '" onclick="sendEvent(' + (i + 2) + ')" >Próximo</button>';
        $("#modal-header").append(header);
        $("#modal-body").append(body);
        $("#modal-footer").append(footer);
    }
```

next I show the modal

```
$('#demo-modal').modal();
```

and To change the pages in modal I use

```
sendEvent = function (step) {
    $('#demo-modal').trigger('next.m.' + step);
}
```

Unfortunately, The modal shows up, but everythin in one window, not spet by step.

Is there any way to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fount out solution for me.

I noticed that first I load the js file for multi-step-modal, and later I add the stuff to this modal, but they don´t have any properties that should have.
So instead of adding the script at the beginning, I load thie script after adding all infos to modal

```
$.getScript("@Url.Content( "~/multi-step-modal.js")");
```

Hope it will help to someone!

Comment: Another solution would be, to create only one modal and then change the date inside of the modal with JavaScript, you can do this with a data id and a normal event